# Rails customized "time_ago_in_words"-ish type model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timeago

Morning, everyone!

I'm working on a Rails app that is just a simple check yes or no, then it displays the `created_at` row and whichever box was checked. My issue is that I need to display the `created_at` as a different value, not the time. If someone created an entry between 4:00 AM - 10:00 AM, it would display **Breakfast** in the view for the `created_at` field. If they created it between 10:00 AM and 2:00 PM, it would display **Lunch**.
I've Googled for hours, and the closest thing I could come up with is some variation of `time_ago_in_words` but nothing really works.
How would I go about implementing something of this nature?

**Full disclosure:** I'm a bit of an amateur at Ruby/RoR. Be gentle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own

```
case created_at.hour
when (4..10)
  "Breakfast"
when (10..14)
  "Lunch"
when (14..22)
  "Supper"
else 
  "Night"
end
```

You can also wrap it as a method or extend `DateTime` class with it

Comment: Seriously? It's that easy? I have a feeling I won't be using PHP for a while :)

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do it in PHP same way. [switch..case operator](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: Right. So far, from what I've seen, you can do the everything with PHP that you can in Ruby. I just think the syntax of Ruby is so much easier and more clean.

Comment: There are count of typical functionality that presents in almost all languages. But no, you can't do everything with PHP that you can in Ruby. At least you can't do it in the same way.